# Create folders from CSV/TXT and move matching column into new directory in Powershell or Batch

Tags: powershell, csv, batch-file

I have a CSV (or XLSX, or TAB - I can export to many) file with about 8000 rows in the format of:

```
|   17854   |   SMITH   |   14785236   |
|   58487   |   JONES   |   96325874   |
|   65715   |   SMITH   |   84682254   | <-- unique via col3
|   65822   |   SMITH   |   14785236   | <-- same as col 2 + 3
```

Some of the data in columns 2 and 3 are identical, while column 1 is always unique (ID).

Inside the destination directory I have the following structure:

```
- 17854
- ...
- 58487
- ...
- 65715
- ...
- 65822
```

Essentially (nearly) every listed ID from column 1 has a folder.

I want to be able to create a folder from the format of column 2 + 3:

```
- JONES 96325874
- SMITH 14785236
- SMITH 84682254
```

and then move the folder matching from column 1 into the respective new directory:

```
- JONES 96325874
---- 58487
- SMITH 14785236
---- 17854
---- 65822
- SMITH 84682254
---- 65715
```

I am able to do the folder creation from editing the file and removing the ID column using either:

```bsh
Set-Location "A:\" 
$Folders = Import-Csv c:\listOfItems.csv
ForEach ($Folder in $Folders) { 
    New-Item $Folder.Name  + $Folder.Number -type directory 
}
```

or originally in a batch file:

```
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%i in (listOfItems.txt) do md "%%i"
```

Is there any way I'd be able to do the move part matching the name of the first column into the combination of column 2 + 3?

I'm not versed well in Powershell but I feel its more targeted for this than a batch script? This would be something I'd have to run every month and manually doing it has been... hard.

Comment: Why did you remove the ID column?  If the csv file is formatted correctly, I don't see a reason as to why you would need to remove it, especially considering it will make what I think you are trying to accomplish much easier.....

Comment: @WilliamHiggs sorry, I had removed it when it was in a batch file, and the `txt` file was just creating names from the lines in the file. which was copied from the CSV file into the text file

Comment: Well, you shouldn't need to do that if you are using powershell.  When you import the csv into powershell, that variable then becomes an array of objects, and the properties of those objects are then the different "columns" in the csv.  You appear to have done a lot of the work already.  I will post what I think you are looking for as answer.

Comment: Sorry @WilliamHiggs - had already mostly typed my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't sell yourself short!!  Based on what you have said, and what I think you want to do, you have already done most of the work.  If I read your question right, all that you need to do now is just move the "id" folder into the folder that you created which includes the "name" and "number" properties.  If that is the case, and assuming that this csv you have imported into powershell has all three columns, you could do something like this

```
$Folders = Import-Csv c:\listOfItems.csv
ForEach ($Folder in $Folders) { 
    New-Item "C:\path\to\createfolder\$($folder.name)`$($Folder.Number)" -type directory 
    Move-Item -Path "C:\path\to\id\folder\$($folder.id)" -Destination "C:\path\to\createfolder\$($folder.name)`$($Folder.Number)\"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following should do what you require, by using the `$Folder.ID` property (if you leave it in the CSV file):

```
ForEach ($Folder in $Folders) { 
    $base = New-Item ($Folder.Name  +" "+ $Folder.Number) -type directory -Force
    Move-Item $Folder.ID $base.FullName
}
```

`-Force` has been added because should you re-run this you need the command to recreate the directory otherwise `$base` will not hold a value. If you want to smarten this up, you could check if the directory exists first and then decide whether to create it.

I'd also like to show a testing method to try before going for the full 8000 records:

```
ForEach ($Folder in $Folders[0..5]) { 
    $base = New-Item ($Folder.Name  +" "+ $Folder.Number) -type directory -Force
    Move-Item $Folder.ID $base.FullName -WhatIf
}
```

By adding `[0..5]` to `$Folders`, the PowerShell will only perform the folder create action for the first 6 (0,1,2,3,4,5) items from the CSV file. The `-WhatIf` switch added to the `Move-Item` CmdLet just shows what PowerShell will do, so you can verify first before taking the `-WhatIf` option off:

```
What if: Performing the operation "Move Directory" on target 
"Item: C:\temp\17854 Destination: C:\temp\SMITH 14785236\17854".
```