# Recreating Folder Structure and moving documents in to correct the folders

Tags: python, powershell

we use a DMS that spits out a document report csv that looks like the one below. The tool that comes with the DMS to export files does not allow you to export folders only documents. I am trying to create PowerShell or python script. To recreate the the folders and move the documents to the folders.

The Report does not include file extensions so they vary.

Column A is the path of the folder from the DMS. 
Column B File name without extension

[Document Report Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Onts.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create folders from CSV/TXT and move matching column into new directory in Powershell or Batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63715596/create-folders-from-csv-txt-and-move-matching-column-into-new-directory-in-power)

Answer (score 0):

you would do this:

```py
# Python program to explain shutil.copyfile() method
 
# importing shutil module
import shutil
 
# Source path
source = "/home/User/Documents/file.txt"
 
# Destination path
destination = "/home/User/Documents/file.txt"
 
# Copy the content of
# source to destination
shutil.copyfile(source, destination)
```

in your particular case you would put this into a loop so that you can complete each one...